# jquery attr("href") returning the same values

Tags: jquery

I have two links called "Read More" (bottom of code) that contain different values. When clicked, they call a jquery function that send it to demo_search.php. Problem is, no matter which link I click, I keep getting the same values. If I were to use

```
var searchString = ($(this).attr("href"))
```

instead of

```
var searchString = ($(".more_info").attr("href"))
```

things work fine. But I cant use `(this)`. How to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dev/ajax/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $(".more_info").click(function() {

        // getting the value that user typed
        var searchString    =($(".more_info").attr("href"));

        // form the queryString
        var data            = 'search='+ searchString;
        var imgLoad         = '<img src="loading.gif">';

        // if searchString is not empty
        if(searchString) {
        alert (searchString);
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:  "demo_search.php",
                data: searchString,
                beforeSend: function(html) { // this happens before actual call

                    $(".word").html(searchString);
                    $(".imgProgress").html(imgLoad);

                },
               success: function(page_data){ // this happens after we get results
                    $("#results").empty();
                    $("#results").fadeIn(200);
                    $("#results").append(page_data);
                    $(".imgProgress").empty();
              },

            });    
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div style="margin:20px auto; text-align: center;">
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_button" /><br />
</form>
</div>      

<div>
<div id="searchresults">Search results for <span class="word"></span><span class="imgProgress"></span></div>
<div id="results" class="update" style="display:none;"><ul></ul>

</div>
<div>
<a href="search=sony&offset=20&lang=en" class="more_info">Read More</a>
<a href="search=pioneer&offset=30&lang=en" class="more_info">Read More</a>
</div>


</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.attr` always returns the corresponding value of the **first** selected element. Why can't you use `this` if it obviously solves your problem?

Comment: Why can't you use (this) ? It pretty much solves the problem

Comment: If I use (this) in this function, can I use it in other functions in the same page/script?

Comment: use $(this). From a previous question of my I learnt that "Inside $.ajax jquery method, "this" is bind to the global window object and not $('#sform')" So I

Comment: It's actually not true. Inside the Ajax callbacks, `this` refers to the jqXHR object. But it does not matter what `this` refers to in other functions, it completely depends on how a function is called and is independent from any other function. Inside an event handler, `this` always refers to the element the handler is bound to. You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`($(".more_info")` will return you a collection of all elements with this class. Unless you specify a specific position in the array  invoking further functions will always target the first element in this collection.
*Compare the change between `searchStringA` and `searchStringB` in the fiddle below when you click on the two different "read more".*

`this` of an invoked function is a JavaScript object and therefore it does not have a method `.attr()` wich belongs to jQuery scope. *See `searchStringC` in the fiddle*

So you have to cast `this` to a jQuery object via `$(this)` and then you can call

```
$(this).attr("href")
```

I stripped down the original code and replaced the `<a>` tags with `<span>` to make it more click friendly :) You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uj6TH/2/).
*I highly recommend it running with an open console to observe the error in the line:*

```
var searchStringC    = this.attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with a class of more_info. This means that your selector yields multiple elements. There's no way you're getting the href of two different elements.

The reason the code works when you use this, is because there is only one clicked on element at a time.

Either you need to continue using this, or you need to write a unique selector, like giving the span an id of more_info_1.

Furthermore, your comments dont seem to make any sense. You write:

// getting the value that user typed
        var searchString    =($(".more_info").attr("href"));

Do you mean to write?

var search = $(".search_box").val();

Comment: Sorry, pls ignore the comments. I simply used something someone else did. The search box has nothing to do here. Only those 2 links and the function they call.